# mysql auto save 10 digit unique number

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, unique

I'm using rails web application with mysql database, I need to auto save 10 digit unique number/alphanumeric for each record in a table.
The table may contain more than millions of records(in future)

**Requirement**:

1. A 10 digit unique number should be generated only from mysql database and the generated number should not be less than 10 digit
2. I also refered the mysql's uuid() and uuid_short() methods which returns a universal unique id, but these returns more than 10 digit number.
3. If generated unique numbers are not in sequence then it will be much better (unpredictable to access other records such as next or previous reocrd).

**NOTE**:

- I don't think it is better to generate the unique id by manually(applying some logic like combination of timestamp, record_id, ...etc), because additional query is needed to check uniqueness in table.

Comment: If you don't want users to be able to access other records, you should probably employ some method other than making the record IDs difficult to guess.  Then you can simply use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column (and add/subtract 10^10 in your application code if desired).

Comment: @eggyal - thanks for quick reply, please help me how to generate and auto save the unique value from mysql such as UUID() and UUID_SHORT() methods